# Pass data from form in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am currently working on a dropdown form in Vue.js. The user should be able to select from what time period he would like to see the data. I would like to then submit his chosen value and call a function in js that will handle his request appropriately.

i have tried to submit the value by "onchange" but have not managed to find the right solution. I am thankful for any help.
this is the code:

```
    <div>
        <div class="stats">
            <!--drop menu-->
            <form>
                <label>Show feeds from <select id="input" name="ddlselect" onchange="submit">
                    <option>Auswählen</option>
                    <option value="Today">Today</option>
                    <option value="ThisWeek">This week</option>
                    <option value="PrevWeek">Previous Week</option>
                </select> </label>
                <br>
            </form>
            <br><br>

            <!--data from the api-->
            <div id="robot_data" v-for="maschine in userdaten.maschinen" :key="maschine.maschineId">
                {{maschine.bezeichnung}}
                <div id="feeds" v-for="feed in maschine.feeds" :key="feed.feedsId">
                    <!--use the var 'today' insted of the date string-->
                    <div v-if="feed.datum >= '2020-10-03' + ' 00:00:00' && feed.datum <= '2020-10-03' + '23:59:59'">
                        ID: {{feed.feedsId}} Datum: {{feed.datum}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: In a glance i can tel you....you missed the v-model directive on select tag and submit should be moved to form tag(v-on:change or @change) as your dealing form..... add your  submit code to question....will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

You want to add your event to the  tag.
Also, the way to use events in Vue is like this v-on:change or @change.

So it should look like this:

```
<form v-on:change="yourMethod">
```

[Here is more info on Vue events.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)